# Does PreparedStatement convert empty strings to null?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, string

I'm working with MySQL and their last available JDBC driver, on a `User` table with `NOT NULL` constraints on all its fields, which are `id`, `name`, `password` and `email`.

In my Java EE application, I first called a simple `Statement` this way :

```
statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO User (name, password, email) "
         + "VALUES ('" + paramName + "', '" + paramPassword + "', '" + paramEmail + "');" );
```

Where `paramName`, `paramPassword` and `paramEmail` are strings. I passed empty strings to this request, and a new line with empty values got successfully inserted in the table, since MySQL considers empty strings different than null entries.

Then, I used a `PreparedStatement` instead :

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement( "INSERT INTO User (name, password, email) VALUES(?, ?, ?);" );
preparedStatement.setString( 1, paramName );
preparedStatement.setString( 2, paramPassword );
preparedStatement.setString( 3, paramEmail );
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

But this time, when I passed empty strings to the request, I got the following error :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'name' cannot be null

**So here's my question** : does the `PreparedStatement`, or maybe its `setString()` method, convert empty strings to null values? I looked it up and didn't find any information about this behavior in the javadoc.

Comment: I also see this behavior in my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of java.sql.PreparedStatatement didn't say anything about this in the method setString. I take a look at the sources of the MySQL ConnectorJ and I didn't find anything too. Are you sure that your String is not null?

Comment: Ok I understood my mistake, strings were indeed null. I naively thought they weren't since the classic `Statement` inserted empty values in the table, but that's only because I directly build my request by concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `NO`. Please make sure that the value of your parameters are not null. Maybe your variable `paramName` is `NULL`.

Comment: This wrong.  Inspection of the JDBC code (OraclePreparedStatement #setStringInternal) clearly shows if length is 0 the value is set to null.